# Return Redirect not working in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to send users to a different page when they click on a specific URL. but return redirect() not working.

```html
[HttpGet("redirectUser/{PlanId}")]
        [ValidateModelState]
        public async Task<IActionResult> redirectUser(Guid PlanId)
        {
             //....
                return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
            }
        }
```

I get this error message in the dev tool. "Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier"
[Failed to load response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Txw.jpg)

Comment: Can you tell us your application version? Whether it is an Asp.net core application or a traditional .NetFramework MVC application? Besides, how do you call the redirectUser endpoint? using the `<a>` tag or using Javascript? I have checked using the `return Redirect("http://www.google.com");` in Asp.net 5 MVC application, and use the `<a>` tag to call the action method, the Redirect() method works well, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diUfP.gif).

Comment: @Raneu: Comment the `[ValidateModelState]` and check again. Perhaps implementation of the attribute is raising the error.